# How to extract a portion of a txt file based on a keyword, in python?

Tags: python, tags, extract

Given a very large text file of ~5000 HTML documents. I am trying to "search" the text file of a specific `DOCNO` and printing all lines of the file until encountering the next `</DOC>` tag.

The text file roughly looks like this:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>abc4567890</DOCNO>
contents 
more contents
<BODY> 
even more contents 
</BODY>
</DOC> 
... repeated roughly 5000 times for different DOC NO's
```

And I am looking for an output of:

```
contents 
more contents
<BODY> 
even more contents 
</BODY>
</DOC>
```

Here is what I've been trying to implement:

```
doc_string = "abc4567890"

with open('myfile.txt', encoding = "utf8") as f:
    for item in f.readlines():
        if "</DOCNO>" in item:
                ID = (item [ item.find("<DOCNO>")+len("<DOCNO>") : ])
                if (ID[0:9] == doc_string):
                    print (item)
                    if "</DOC>" in item:
                       break
```

But, as an output, I am getting:

```
<DOCNO>abc4567890</DOCNO>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
# initialize variables:
lines = []
read_lines = False

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:

    # iterate over each line:    
    for line in file.readlines():

        # append line to lines list:
        if read_lines: lines.append(line)

        # set read_lines to True:
        if '<DOCNO>abc4567890</DOCNO>' in line: read_lines = True

        # set read_lines to Flase:
        if '</DOC>' in line: read_lines = False


# print each line:
for line in lines:
    print(line, end='')
```

Given your input, it will output:

```
contents 
more contents
<BODY> 
even more contents 
</BODY>
</DOC>
```

Comment: This iterates thru the entire file and prints every line between</DOC> and </DOCNO>. But, I only want to do that for 1 document with the specific DOCNO. The document is comprised of ~5000 DOCNO's

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You can change the condition that sets `read_lines` to true and break the loop when you are done reading. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Trying this for several DOCNO's, this code only works for the first DOCNO. For the others, it does not print anything

Comment: Ok, then in that case we can remove the break statement and go back to setting read_line to False. I've edited my answer to reflect this.